# How do you JOIN two tables as a combination of LEFT and RIGHT JOINs?

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb-10.5

This is probably a stupid question. In two [tables](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=c9baeae1b718894c69e0e035436880fb) of

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
col1 int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE t2
(
id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
col2 int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO t1 (id,col1) VALUES (1,2), (3,5), (11,3);
INSERT INTO t2 (id,col2) VALUES (1,1), (3,4), (10,2);
```

How do you `JOIN` tables to include missing ids too?

```
id  col1    col2
1   2       1
3   5       4
10  NULL    2
11  3       NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically its an unimplemented (so far) [full outer join](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13648) but you can fake it with:

```
SELECT t2.id AS id, col1, col2
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 USING id
UNION ALL
(SELECT t1.id, col1, col2
FROM t2
LEFT JOIN t1 USING id
WHERE col1 IS NULL
)
```